# how to call excel forecast function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, typescript

I'm trying to convert excel sheet contents and functions to my react project.

I've encountered convert FORECAST.ETS and FORECAST.LINEAR to typescript code.

Should I have to create excel file and insert my data to excel and run FORECAST.ETS and FORECAST.LINEAR then crop the value?

Is this the only way to call excel forecast function in javascript?

Comment: Why not understand what forecast does then reproduce the maths in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the answer on a prior question to get help with using forecast. It provided a function I was able to use in order to calculate the forecast amount correctly. Maybe it will help you too.

[Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373328/forecast-formula-from-excel-in-javascript)

```js
function forecast(x, ky, kx){
   var i=0, nr=0, dr=0,ax=0,ay=0,a=0,b=0;
   function average(ar) {
          var r=0;
      for (i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
         r = r+ar[i];
      }
      return r/ar.length;
   }
   ax=average(kx);
   ay=average(ky);
   for (i=0;i<kx.length;i++){
      nr = nr + ((kx[i]-ax) * (ky[i]-ay));
      dr = dr + ((kx[i]-ax)*(kx[i]-ax))
   }
  b=nr/dr;
  a=ay-b*ax;
  return (a+b*x);
}
```

Example:
forecast(30, [6,7,9,15,21], [20,28,31,38,40] );

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable.